# Postgres outputting an array in PSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql, array

I have the following function. It is something I am building and want to show the contents of stuff_list so I can prove it is working correctly. I can't however work out what output type I should be using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isf.update_tbl_variadic(VARIADIC _stuff_array stuff[])
  RETURNS SETOF BIGINT[]
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
    stuff_list BIGINT[];
BEGIN
    
    stuff_list:= ARRAY (
        SELECT id
    FROM stuff As s
    WHERE s."id"
    IN (
    SELECT t.id
    FROM unnest(_stuff_array) as t(
       id,
       x,
       y,
       created
   )))
 FOR UPDATE;

    RAISE NOTICE '%', stuff_list;
    RETURN stuff_list;
END;
$$;
```

Is anyone able to help me with this please? I need to generate an array from this to be used in a subsequent query, but for now I just need to see the output.

Comment: Did you run `SET client_min_messages = notice;` before calling your function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the function is declared as

```
RETURNS SETOF bigint[]
```

You need [`RETURN NEXT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#id-1.8.8.8.3.4):

```
RETURN NEXT stuff_list;
```

Alternatively, to return a single array:

```
RETURNS bigint[]
...
RETURN stuff_list;
```

Or to return a *set* of bigint:

```
RETURNS SETOF bigint
...
RETURN QUERY SELECT unnest(stuff_list);
```

(Or return IDs directly, instead of aggregating and unnesting back.)

Comment: Thank you Erwin :)